# Many connections in TIME_WAIT state in connection pool, using either static or single HttpClient instance in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient, connection-pooling

I've been strugling for days trying to prevent multiple connections in pool when using HttpClient

I've built a REST WebApi from which I'm calling an external endpoint by using HttpClient inside of it. A controller's action is called multiple times by a client in order to perform aforementioned external call.

Previously I was using WebClient but it suffered of SocketExhaustation when several requests were made. Searching on the web I found that migrating to HttpWebClient will solve my issues if used statically or within a singleton. I even tried to implement IHttpClientFactory but it was useless, as I experienced the same issue on my injected services.

This is my current implementation, after several refactors. Sorry if currently this code is not optimal but after multiple rewritings this was my last resort.

```cs
public static class CustomHttpClientManager
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(
            new SocketsHttpHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new CustomProxy(),
                UseProxy = true,
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 2,
                CookieContainer = cookies,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            });

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetAsString(string url){
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try{

                HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get
                };

                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
                
                response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);    
                if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();   
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                return $"Could not fetch response from: {connectionParameters.Url}, due to: {ex.Message}";     
            }
            finally{
                if(response != null){
                    response.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The callstack until reaching the current code goes like this:

1. At Startup the WebApi app calls `CustomHttpClientManager`'s `Initialize` method, which instantiates the `HttpClient` only once.
2. A client calls WebApi controller's action.
3. The action calls a business logic class (service class)
4. The logic class uses the `CustomHttpClientManager`'s `GetAsString` method to perform the external call by using previously instantiated `HttpClient`

The client performs a lot of calls to the WebApi (around 200 rq per minute), and when running `netstat -ano` on the command prompt, it shows a quite long list of pooled connections whose status is TIME_WAIT, which shows that `HttpClient` is not reusing connections from the pool at all. These connections only dissappear around 2 minutes after being used.

Besides this code my other approaches were.

- Injecting `IHttpClientFactory` on Startup by using `.AddHttpClient()`
- Using the same class above, but using a thread safe singleton version.

None of them worked. I don't know what else to do. This has driven me crazy for around 2 days straight.

I've tested this implementation from a simple console app, and the issue is not happening. This suggests me that somehow WebApi action keeps closing the external connection once a reply to its caller has been given, and once another call is made, it creates another connection in the pool and it goes on and on for the next incomming requests as well.

BTW, I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `IHttpClientFactory` is the way to go and should do the trick. No idea what went wrong, when you tried. But this is certainly the way I found recommended the most often.

Comment: @Fildor I've also found that `IHttpClientFactory` is the most recommended approach, nevertheless, I've tried injecting to either the service class I'm using, and when it didn't work I tried injecting it through the controller of the action (this can be done if no service class is specified when using `.AddHttpClient()`) I'm calling, but this approach had the same behaviour as well.

Comment: Hard to tell, without seeing that approach. Maybe you just missed by an inch.

Comment: @Fildor I doubt I'd missed something as I tried it just by following the MSDocs example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-request and implementing it the simplest way possible. I just used ´services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>();´ and then in `MyService` I just set HttpClient field through its constructor as stated at the `"Implement your Typed Client classes that use the injected and configured HttpClient"` section, and that was all.

Comment: And you did set the Handler Liftime? `services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>()
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));`

Comment: ^^ That's important, because `services.AddHttpClient` registeres the service transient. So each request => new Service => new HttpClient ... but those share one Handler. You just have to set its lifetime.

Comment: I just added SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); as you recommended, nonetheless, it kept creating and closing connections over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Using the

PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),

means that the connection is removed form the pool after 30s.

You may change that to be longer (e.g. 10 mins) - bot not too long to accommodate
the DNS changes.